# Why isn't my method working for writing a file using a HashMap to txt file

Tags: java, hashmap, bluej

I am not entirely sure why my method is not working. I am using a write a file method which basically uses a HashMap to write to an external text file. which is the below

```
   public void writeAMap(HashMap<String, String> map, String filename)
    {
        if(map != null) {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true)) {
                for(String key : map.keySet()) {
                    String value = map.get(key);
                    if(value == null) {
                        System.out.println("Warning: Null response for " +
                                           key + " in writeAMap. Using a default.");
                        value = "I don't know what you mean?";
                    }
                    writer.write(key.trim());
                    writer.write('\n');
                    writer.write(value.trim());
                    writer.write('\n');
                }                    
                writer.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Problem writing file: " + filename +
                                   " in writeAMap");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Null map passed to writeAMap.");
        }
    }
```

I am then calling the above method, using the method below in a another class

```
 public void mapWrite(HashMap<String, String>map)
    {
        help.writeAMap(map, "responses.txt");

    }
```

Then I wrote the below method in order to call the above method in the main class,

```
if (input.contains("write")) {

                     HashMap<String, String> key = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     instruct.mapWrite(key);
                }
```

This compiles fine and gives no errors, but it isn't actually writing to the external txt file. any help on figuring out why that is would be great.

Comment: To get answers sooner and more detailed ones provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Don't call `writer.close();` inside your try block. It should be done in `finally` block or since you are using try-with-resources you can skip it entirely.

Comment: Put something in the map and maybe it works...

Comment: Your `writeAMap(HashMap<String, String> map, String filename)` method works fine for me.

Comment: Does it write to an external txt file?

Comment: the main filehelper isn't the issue it is using it in external classes.